# Close work items automatically on Release to specific environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Is there a way to close Azure Boards Work Items associated with a PR automatically, after the PR had been released to a specific environment (and not when PR is merged to master)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the REST API "[Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs From Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-work-items-refs-from-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to get all the work items that associated with the build of the release. It will list the IDs and URLs of the work items.
[image]

Then you can use API "[Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to change the State of the work  items to be Closed.

You just need to add a script task (such as [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) or [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)) as the last step of the deployment job, and use this script task to call above REST API. And set this script task runs only when all the previous tasks are successful.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, thanks a lot! WIll try this.

Comment: @Bright Ran-MSFT How does one make sure a new build only lists the Delta since last build for associated commit/workitems?