# Azure ADO branching and release strategy to only include delta since last build to show as associated WorkItems with a build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My question is a continuation to this post:
[Close work items automatically on Release to specific environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532372/close-work-items-automatically-on-release-to-specific-environment/70542832#70542832)

This accepted answer will work perfectly, but only if I can make sure that a build shows just the delta since last build as associated WorkItems, instead of all work items from history. Sometimes I see all items in history as associated work items in a build.
[image]

Builds are happening for several environments (Dev, QA, UAT, Prod). How do I make sure that when I run a new build, it only has delta since the last build in that same environment so that I am only looking at new changes that are coming in with a new build?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I think I get what you mean. Please see if my understanding is accurate: your master branch has many PRs and links to many workitems. You create release1 from the master, and then when the branch is run based on release1 for the first time, the API lists the associated workitems of all the commits of the master. The second time, the incremental workitem compared to the first time can be displayed normally. Later, you created release2 from the master. When the branch was run based on release2 for the first time, the API listed the associated workitems of all commits of the master(This is not you want.). The second time, the incremental workitem compared to the first time can be displayed normally. . What you want is to display incremental workitems from the last run of the branch based on release1 the first time the branch is run based on release2?

If so, it's obviously not possible to use this API to achieve the requirements. As I said in the answer, this API fetch increment refers to the increment based on the same branch, it does not apply to different branches.

But you still have a way to get the "increment" you want, check out this API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-work-items-between-builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

You just need to compare.

**Original Answer:**

> but only if I can make sure that a build shows just the delta since
> last build as associated WorkItems, instead of all work items from
> history. Sometimes I see all items in history as associated work items
> in a build.

Why do you say 'make sure'?

The API should only get the delta workitems(under the same branch).

I think changes should not contain all of the work items linked to all of the previous commits(since it is only 'changes').

Do you mean the behavior on your side is unstable, do you mean sometimes contains delta changes but sometimes contains all of the changes during the branch lifecycle?

If not, then the understood of yours maybe a little false.

If yes, I think you need to report this issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem). Please also provide your problematic build url there in this situation. StackOverflow is an open forum, so it's not suitable for handling stuff with private information.

> Builds are happening for several environments (Dev, QA, UAT, Prod).
> How do I make sure that when I run a new build, it only has delta
> since the last build in that same environment so that I am only
> looking at new changes that are coming in with a new build?

I suggest you put each environment in a different branch, then when you run pipeline based on the related branch, the pipeline should only get the delta changes of current branch and the API should only get the delta workitem commits since the last pipeline run of current branch.

Comment: Hi Bowman, thanks for your answer. I found out whats causing all workitems from history to show up with a build. For every new release we create a new branch from master (release/1.5. release/1.6 etc). The first time this newly created release branch is deployed, all PRs show up. The next time we create a PR from master to this release branch to bring recent changes in, then it just shows the delta since last release. Are we doing release branches the wrong way (by creating a new release branch for each release from master)?

Comment: What we do is for example:
After release 1.5 is deployed to prod, the next day we create a new release/1.6 branch from master. The first time we create this branch and build it  (for a deployment to QA env), all PRs show up. 2 days later if we create a PR from master to this new branch to move the latest changes to the QA environment then only the delta shows up.

Comment: @user1102532 StackOverflow said my comment is too long, I posted it in the answer.

Comment: @user1102532 any update on this? have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, I did thanks for your answer. I believe another way that I have is, instead of cutting our new release branch everytime from master, I will have to cut it from previous release branch and then create a PR from master, so that only delta work-items are showing.